# Get value from external client database for a column value as a key in spark dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to fetch a value from another java based database resource for a given column value.

I have followed the below process

```
//sample method 
object testObject extends Serializable {
def method1(key: String) = Database[String,String] {
return dbdetails 
}

val data : Database[String,String] = method1.testObject(x)

val getUdf = udf((value: String) => data.get(value))

val resultingDF = df.withColumn("test", lit(getUdf(col("value"))))
```

say if the get from the database returns String value "abc", I am expecting it to be stored in the dataframe. But it throws an error while calling UDF as below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable.
```

I tried using extends Serializable, but still error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your method as an object:

```
object testObject extends Serializable {
val method1(key: String) = Database[String,String] {
return dbdetails 
}
```